# How to get an ACCESS_TOKEN from the new Add to Timeline Auth dialog

Tags: facebook, oauth, authentication, access-token

I currently have the following situation. On my website, the user can access his settings page. This page features a tab called 'Facebook'. On this page, I have the following code that  lets the user allow my website to post to his timeline when completing a certain action:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#appId={APP_ID_HERE}&xfbml=1";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

<div class="fb-add-to-timeline" data-show-faces="false" data-mode="button"></div>
```

When the user clicks the button, it is forwarded to the Add to Timeline dialog. When the user clicks Allow, the user gets redirected back to his settings page on my website.

The question is; how do I get an access token out of this? I need a user access token to post to his timeline, according to this line from the tutorial:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me/YOUR_NAMESPACE:cook?recipe=OBJECT_URL&access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN
```

Answer (score 0):

Just tell user to get log in

```
<fb:login></fb:login>
```

and after that, use this code everywhere you want

```
  FB.api(
  '/me/NAMESPACE:cook','post', {recipe:'http://samples.ogp.me/214706465259448'}, 
  function(response) {  
         //posted  
  });
```

Where **cooking** is an object

Comment: So they need to login first, and _then also_ use the Add To Timeline dialog? Isn't it possible to reduce this to only 1 step?

Comment: Thanks, but I want to post to the Timeline using PHP, using cURL to POST to the URL shown in my first post.

Comment: @VorteX: so just send his/her access token via ajax request

Comment: I don't want people to have complete more than 1 step to connect with Facebook and Add To Timeline. I hope there's a way to get an access token from the Add To Timeline Auth dialog.

Comment: @VorteX: ehm. You do not need php to be able to post to their timeline. Just use code I posted and you need only one step - login

Comment: Please read my question; I **don't** want to use JavaScript, I **want** to use PHP.

Comment: @VorteX: and my question is, why?

Comment: That's just how my site works, the action the user takes is not executed via JavaScript.

Comment: @VorteX: in that case AJAX won't help, nor JS FB API